# MS SQL Server 2008 Link server query says "Invalid Object Name" but still works

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query has a red squiggly underlining for the server through to the table this bit `[OtherServer].[UAT_DB].[dbo].[profileTable]` and when hovering says `Invalid Object Name`, but interestingly if I execute the line it returns the correct records from the linked server table:-

```
select * from [OtherServer].[UAT_DB].[dbo].[profileTable]
```

Comment: That can be problem with not refreshed IntelliSense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refreshing the local intellisense cache might fix it.

Whilst in a query window, either:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Go to the Edit menu -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache

Comment: Bridge thanks, unfortunately this didn't fix it. The query still returns the correct rows as does a more compled join across the two servers.

Answer (score 15):

Intellisense in sql server works fine for queries on the same server. But when it comes to run a query on a remote server then it doesn't really know how to deal with it.

For certainty intellisense will not work with a remote server that has a version that does not support intellisense. For instance if the remote database has a compatibility level of 80(SQL 2000).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, i.e. Intellisence doen't work across servers.

Comment: Just adding that my experience is really inconsistent, here.  2016 server linked to a 2000 server.  Some queries/tables/fields it does not complain about.  Others it does.  Sometimes it is fine with an entire query, except for a single field.  I don't think it's as simple as "doesn't work with linked servers or old servers".

Answer (score 1):

I had to use an **ALIAS** in order for it to work.

Example:

```
select * from [OtherServer].[UAT_DB].[dbo].[profileTable] myalias
where myalias.profileid = 1
```